# Why am I getting errors in my for loop in jsp?

Tags: jsp

This is my error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/WebApp] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /homepage.jsp at line 24

```
<table align="center">
<tr>
<th>姓</th>
<th>名</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>メールアドレス</th>
</tr>
<%
List<AddressBean> addressList = (List<AddressBean>)request.getAttribute("addressList");
**for (AddressBean ab : addressList) {**
%>
<tr>
<td><%=ab.getLastName()%></td>
<td><%=ab.getFirstName()%></td>
<td><%=ab.getEmail()%></td>
</tr>
<%
}
%>
</table>
```

Comment: what's the stacktrace?

Comment: 1) Show the full stacktrace (i.e. what is the exception); 2) Use [JSTL](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnake.html); 3) If you are - most probably - getting NullPointerException, then your `addressList` attribute if not initialized properly, check your controller.

Comment: Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:579)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: @JozefChocholacek can i message you directly? i'm really desperate cause i have to do a presentation for this tomorrow

Comment: @user7294900 java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.jsp.homepage_jsp._jspService (homepage_jsp.java: 138)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service (HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java: 729)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service (JspServletWrapper.java: 438)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile (JspServlet.java: 396)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service (JspServlet.java: 340)

Comment: HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String login_auth = (String) session.getAttribute("login_auth");
String path = "login.html";
if (login_auth != null) {

   path = "homepage.jsp";
   List<AddressBean> addressList = new ArrayList<AddressBean>();

   AddressDAO dao = new AddressDAO();

   try {
    addressList = dao.selectAddress();
    request.setAttribute("addressList", addressList);
   } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(path);
  rd.forward(request, response);

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:560)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
原因

Comment: Did you debug the controller code? It looks that either `dao.selectAddress()` returns `null`, or it throws an exception. Check the `catalina.out` file if you find there a stacktrace report from the `e.printStackTrace();` line.

Comment: Btw. it's better to edit the question and put the stacktrace and controller code there, because it's very hard to read it in a comment (because of missing formatting).